# Firefox can't create temp dir for guest user in lightdm

Tags: lightdm, 22.04, guest-session

I've setup latest Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy) to use lightdm, and enabled the guest account via a lightdm config.

This seems to work fine, and can login with an ephemeral guest account that gets removed on logout.

However, it appears that Firefox can't start, due to being unable to create temp files (`/tmp/guest-dheud/snap/firefox/1443`). It's strange to me that any user couldnt write to /tmp, what could fix this? Gonna hash more out and see what can be done but didn't know if anyone could give a nudge

Specific error message:

`cannot create user data directory: /tmp/guest-hfuebh/snap/firefox/1443: Permission denied`

The interesting part here is the directory seems to exist, and writable by the guest user.. unsure why it says permission denied. Does Firefox run as a snap as default?

Looking into it, I found that the guest user's home directory actually is `/tmp/guest-fsdfdew/`, which is probably the source of my woes... This isn't a problem when the user's home is in `/home`, but an issue when it exists in `/tmp`... is is possible to set `lightdm` to create the home dir in `/home` instead?

Update:

Looks like changing the guest's home dir to `/home` is harder than thought. I have tweaked the `/usr/bin/guest-account` script to make the dir in the desired place, but something is killing the session when the session starts (nothing helpful in `lightdm.log`, just says Session exited with return value 1), and can't find any `.xsession-errors`.

Comment: yes Firefox is a snap nowadays.  Especially in 22.04 and later.  This may be part of the problem.

Comment: Yeah agreed. Looking up ways to allow for snaps to access things, but nothing immediately obvious. I know snap has some perm management stuff but can't remember exactly how to do it

Comment: I'm not in front of my computer but when I am i will check my snaps documentation

Comment: Yeah I see either letting snap access /tmp, or getting lightdm to create the home dir in /home/, rather than /tmp/. Either should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling Firefox with the regular `.deb`, via this guide: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04